# Spring AOP runs in reveres order

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am currently experiencing something pretty weird. I have to Aspect classes, both of them have the same pointcut in an AfterThrowing tag.
The Aspect classes are ordered, but always the lower priority one runs first, which I believe is the opposite of the expected behaviour.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class AspectOne {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void doSomething(JoinPoint jp, Exception ex){
    System.out.println("AspectOne");
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Aspect
@Order(2)
public class AspectTwo {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void doSomething(JoinPoint jp, Exception ex){
    System.out.println("AspectTwo");
}
```

According to the documentations, the smaller the number is, the higher the presedence is.
Yet my output is:

- AspectTwo
- AspectOne

If I switch the order, the result will also change. So The Order is working, but the opposite way it is supposed to. I tried with different numbers, the results are the same.

Comment: There is one thing to understand about ordering **and** the after advices. The order works on the aspect and works as it should. However the after advices are executed in **reverse** order. Non-related but please remove the `@Configurateion` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` just create 1config class that does this, ann make your aspects regular `@Component` classes.

Comment: Thanks!
Could you please elaborate why I should remove Configuration and EnableAspectJAutoproxy annotations?

Comment: It is an aspect not a configuration class and thus just a regular `@Component`. Create an `AopConfiguration` class with the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)` or add it to your main configuration class. Mainly due to you can only have a single `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and `@Configuration` classes are processed differently then regular `@Component` beans. and your aspects aren't configuration so as such remove those annotations, use the proper ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order works on the aspect and works as it should. However the after advices are executed in **reverse** order.

Imagine your aspects having both an `@Before` and `@After`

```java
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(1)
public class AspectOne {

@Before(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))")
public void soSomethingBefore(Joinpoint jp) {
    System.out.println("[BEFORE] AspectOne");
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void doSomething(JoinPoint jp, Exception ex){
    System.out.println("[AFTER ] AspectOne");
}
```

and

```java
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(2)
public class AspectTwo {

@Before(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))")
public void soSomethingBefore(Joinpoint jp) {
    System.out.println("[BEFORE] AspectTwo");
}

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "exection(* com.test.*..*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void doSomething(JoinPoint jp, Exception ex){
    System.out.println("[AFTER ] AspectTwo");
}
```

If you would look at the output it would be

```
[BEFORE] AspectOne
[BEFORE] AspectTwo
[AFTER ] AspectTwo
[AFTER ] AspeectOne
```

So the ordering is honored however you have to take into consideration that after advices are in the reverse order.

You might wonder why?

Lets take an `@Around` advice which is basically an `@Before` and an `@After` advice. If the first aspect would be about starting a transaction, it should be the **last** to commit/rollback the transaction, as everything in between should participate in the same transaction. If it would be the first to start and commit other parts of the execution wouldn't be part of the tx, possibly leading to weird issues.

**NOTE:** Please remove the `@Configuration` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` just create 1 config class that does this, and make your aspects regular `@Component` classes.